# Nesting child comments using underscore with 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to do this. I have 1 single object that looks like:

```
var comments = [{
    id: 1,
    deleted: 0,
    comment: 'I am the parent commenter',
    created: 'Sun Mar 01 2014 18: 16: 53 GMT - 0800(PST)',
    parent_id: null,
    username: 'edmund'
}, {
    id: 2,
    deleted: 0,
    comment: 'I am a reply',
    created: 'Sun Mar 02 2014 18: 16: 59 GMT - 0800(PST)',
    parent_id: 1,
    username: 'sally'
}, {
    id: 3,
    deleted: 0,
    comment: 'I'm also a reply',
    created: 'Sun Mar 03 2014 18: 16: 59 GMT - 0800(PST)',
    parent_id: 1,
    username: 'susan'
}];
```

It contains comments, and if a comment has a non-null `parent_id`, then it's a child. So I'm splitting these into 2 arrays like so:

```
var parents = [], children = [];

_(comments).filter(function(comment) {
    comment.parent_id === null ? parents.push(comment) : children.push(comment);
});
```

Now what is the best way to append all children for a particular parent comment? I was thinking something like this:

```
children.forEach(function(child) {
  parents[child['parent_id']]['children'] = _.where(children, { parent_id : child.parent_id });
});
```

Is there a way I can combine all of these

Comment: Can a child also be a parent?

Comment: @TedHopp A child will never be a parent (I'm only nesting one level deep).

Comment: @bob_cobb your goal is to make tree comment list, isnt'it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`_.groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy), like this

```
console.log(_.groupBy(comments, "parent_id"));
```

That gives

```
{ '1': 
   [ { id: 2,
       deleted: 0,
       comment: 'I am a reply',
       created: 'Sun Mar 02 2014 18: 16: 59 GMT - 0800(PST)',
       parent_id: 1,
       username: 'sally' },
     { id: 3,
       deleted: 0,
       comment: 'I\'m also a reply',
       created: 'Sun Mar 03 2014 18: 16: 59 GMT - 0800(PST)',
       parent_id: 1,
       username: 'susan' } ],
  null: 
   [ { id: 1,
       deleted: 0,
       comment: 'I am the parent commenter',
       created: 'Sun Mar 01 2014 18: 16: 53 GMT - 0800(PST)',
       parent_id: null,
       username: 'edmund' } ] }
```

Now, if the key is `null` they all are parents and all the other elements are the `parent_id`s

```
var _ = require("underscore");
var groupedData = _.groupBy(comments, "parent_id");
var parents = groupedData["null"], children = _.omit(groupedData, "null");
console.log("Children:", children);
console.log("Parents:", parents);
```

**Output**

```
Children: { '1': 
   [ { id: 2,
       deleted: 0,
       comment: 'I am a reply',
       created: 'Sun Mar 02 2014 18: 16: 59 GMT - 0800(PST)',
       parent_id: 1,
       username: 'sally' },
     { id: 3,
       deleted: 0,
       comment: 'I\'m also a reply',
       created: 'Sun Mar 03 2014 18: 16: 59 GMT - 0800(PST)',
       parent_id: 1,
       username: 'susan' } ] }

Parents: [ { id: 1,
    deleted: 0,
    comment: 'I am the parent commenter',
    created: 'Sun Mar 01 2014 18: 16: 53 GMT - 0800(PST)',
    parent_id: null,
    username: 'edmund' } ]
```

To get the [expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139457/nesting-child-comments-using-underscore-with-2-arrays/22139530?noredirect=1#comment33594419_22139530), you can use this

```
var _ = require("underscore");
var groupedData = _.groupBy(comments, "parent_id");
console.log(_.map(groupedData["null"], function(currentItem) {
    return _.defaults(currentItem, {"children": groupedData[currentItem.id]});
}));
```

**Output**

```
[ { id: 1,
    deleted: 0,
    comment: 'I am the parent commenter',
    created: 'Sun Mar 01 2014 18: 16: 53 GMT - 0800(PST)',
    parent_id: null,
    username: 'edmund',
    children: 
     [ { id: 2,
         deleted: 0,
         comment: 'I am a reply',
         created: 'Sun Mar 02 2014 18: 16: 59 GMT - 0800(PST)',
         parent_id: 1,
         username: 'sally' },
       { id: 3,
         deleted: 0,
         comment: 'I\'m also a reply',
         created: 'Sun Mar 03 2014 18: 16: 59 GMT - 0800(PST)',
         parent_id: 1,
         username: 'susan' } ] } ]
```

Comment: +1. This does most of the job, but it falls just short of what OP wants. It requires a second step to add a `children` attribute to each of the parent comments, setting it to the array at the corresponding `parent_id` attribute of the `groupBy` result.

Comment: @TedHopp Please check now, I have included a way to separate `parents` and `children`.

Comment: Nice! Is there a good underscore method to merge (nest) the children within the parents?

Comment: @bob_cobb Can you please give an example?

Comment: Yep, looks good. I don't think you need to construct the `children` object using `_omit`. Wouldn't the `groupedData` object would work just as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to build a tree - to merge nested child elements like 1 > 1.1 > 1.1.1 you can use this recursion:

```
var raw = [
    { title : 'element_1', id : 1 },
    { title : 'element_2' , id : 2 },
    { title : 'element_3' , id : 3 },
    { title : 'element_11', id : 11, parent_id : 1 },
    { title : 'element_12' , id : 12, parent_id : 1 },
    { title : 'element_21', id : 21, parent_id : 2 },
    { title : 'element_22' , id : 22, parent_id : 2 },
    { title : 'element_31', id : 31, parent_id : 3 },
    { title : 'element_32' , id : 32, parent_id : 3 },
    { title : 'element_331', id : 331, parent_id : 33 },
    { title : 'element_332' , id : 332, parent_id : 33 },
    { title : 'element_111', id : 111, parent_id : 11 },
    { title : 'element_113' , id : 113, parent_id : 11 }
],

roots = {},
childs = {};

function tree(item) {
    for (c in childs[item.id]){
        var el = childs[item.id][c];

        item.nodes = item.nodes || [];
        item.nodes.push(el);

        childs[el.id] && tree(el);
    }
}

for (item in raw){
    if(!raw[item].parent_id){
        roots[item] = raw[item];
    } else { 
        var p_id = raw[item].parent_id;

        childs[p_id] = childs[p_id] || [];
        childs[p_id].push(raw[item])
    }
}

for (i in roots){
    tree(roots[i])
}

console.log(roots);
```